# What does "_localserver_view" mean after an MSDB Database table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, msdb

What is equal to the database table
`[msdb]. [dbo]. [sysschedules_localserver_view]`, which contains the suffix `_localserver_view`?

I am having a permissions problem with a `[msdb].[Dbo].[Sp_help_schedule]`, and I noticed the user I chose to run this *stored procedure*, *select* access in the table `[msdb].[dbo].[sysbobschedules]` more than when accessing the table `[msdb]. [dbo].[sysschedules_localserver_view]` (which is executed by an internal command from `[msdb].[dbo].[sp_help_schedule]`) is nothing.

Also note that this table does not exist in the `msdb` database, or in the *table*, *view*, or *stored procedure* folders.

Why would you want to know what this `_localserver_view` extension changes in the permissions or in the table view.

Comment: Well i do  see the [dbo]. [sysschedules_localserver_view] view in my system views in the msdb database. The view selects from the tables:  msdb.dbo.sysoriginatingservers and msdb.dbo.sysschedules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question but I'll try to explain the differences.

**When you have full permissions in `msdb`**
you'll get the same rows when

- executing `msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule`
- selecting from `msdb.dbo.sysschedules_localserver_view`
- selecting from `msdb.dbo.sysschedules`

This is because `msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule` selects from `msdb.dbo.sysschedules_localserver_view` which selects from `msdb.dbo.sysschedules`.

You'll get less rows when select from `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules` mentioned in your question, this is because `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules`

> Contains schedule information for jobs to be executed by SQL Server
>   Agent.

While `msdb.dbo.sysschedules` shows also schedules currently not related to any existing job, for example is contains schedules for Data Collector that may not be configured.

**When the user has only `select` permission in `msdb`**

he will not be able to execute `msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule`, he'll get the full result when selecting from **tables** `msdb.dbo.sysschedules` and `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules`, but he'll get no rows when selecting from the `msdb.dbo.sysschedules_localserver_view` **view**.

This is because this view contains the `where` clause:

```
WHERE (svr.master_server = 0)
  AND ( (sched.owner_sid = SUSER_SID())
        OR (ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0) = 1)
      OR (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'SQLAgentReaderRole'), 0) = 1)
      )
```

This means that to get any row from this view one of the following should be true for the current user:

- user is `owner` of the job (and only the schedules related to owned jobs will
  be returned)
- corresponding login is a member of `sysadmin` fixed server role (all rows will be returned)
- user is a member of `SQLAgentReaderRole` database role (all rows will be
  returned)